# How to use one background image for five buttons in Android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview, android-button

I am going to use this image for background of five buttons, but I don't know how to achieve this purpose, should I split this image into five parts? how can I make sure it can display correctly after splitting

If I don't want to split the image, is it possible to add five different onClickListener to different areas of the ImageView?

[image]

Comment: I would just check where the user click with an OnTouchListener.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by setting the background of `ImageButtons` to `transparent` and keeping a the image as a background of a container view like a `RelativeLayout` or any other layout.

`android:background="@android:color/transparent"` will set the background of your ImageButtons transparent. Here is an example of code I use for such situations

```
<RelativeLayout
            android:layout_height="@dimen/widthHeightCenterDial"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/widthHeightCenterDial"
            android:background="@drawable/my_background"
            android:id="@+id/frameLayout">


            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="@dimen/widthHeightCenterDial"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/widthHeightCenterDial"
                android:id="@+id/cdSureButn"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:textAlignment="center" />
            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="@dimen/widthHeightCenterDial"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/widthHeightCenterDial"
                android:id="@+id/status_o_ring"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:visibility="visible"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:contentDescription="status orange ring" />

           ....


   </RelativeLayout>
```

I use this approach to achieve something like this

[image]

Comment: How do you align these 8 buttons around the circle in RelativeLayout? could you show the complete xml example?

Comment: used a `RelativeLayout` and set height and  width to `wrap_content`. Placed the dial image inside it along with another  `RelativeLayout` with height and  width set to `match_parent`. Placed the buttons in this one. setting positions relative to each other. Works fine on all screens sizes

Answer (score 0):

No you cant set five onClickListeners to an image view what you need to do is to make this rounded view and put in it five imageviews each one holding respective icon and then set to each imageview and onClickListener,
For diong this rounded view use some layout techniques like  and ..